# How can I sort A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,...,AA1,AA2,AA3 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
+--------+
| Square |
+--------+
| A1     |
| A10    |
| A2     |
| A3     |
| A4     |
| A5     |
| A6     |
| A7     |
| A8     |
| A9     |
| B1     |
| B10    |
| B2     |
| B3     |
| B4     |
| B5     |
| B6     |
| B7     |
| B8     |
| B9     |
```

...

```
| AA1    |
| AA10   |
| AA2    |
| AA3    |
| AA4    |
| AA5    |
| AA6    |
| AA7    |
| AA8    |
| AA9    |
+--------+
```

The prefix runs from A#-Z#, then goes AA#-ZZ# and continues, with a maximum of 2 letters (i.e. it will never go over ZZ). The number suffix can be any length (i.e. A1,A10,A100,A1000,etc.).

How can I sort these and have the result set come out as follows:

```
+--------+
| Square |
+--------+
| A1     |
| A2     |
| A3     |
| A4     |
| A5     |
| A6     |
| A7     |
| A8     |
| A9     |
| A10    |
| B1     |
| B2     |
| B3     |
| B4     |
| B5     |
| B6     |
| B7     |
| B8     |
| B9     |
| B10    |
```

...

```
| AA1    |
| AA2    |
| AA3    |
| AA4    |
| AA5    |
| AA6    |
| AA7    |
| AA8    |
| AA9    |
| AA10   |
+--------+
```

Comment: Do you realize it's inefficient?

Comment: @zerkms Inefficient? I have an interface in which it is required that I display them in the order described. Are you saying you know a solution, but it is inefficient?

Comment: do you also have `AAA`, `AAAA`, or even `ZZZZZ`?

Comment: @JW No. The description states that it is a max of 2 letters for the prefix.

Comment: @Travis: it's inefficient to store it in that not DB friendly way. "I have an interface in which it is required that I display them in the order described" --- that's it. Even though it should be displayed in that way, it doesn't mean it should be stored in that way. Don't mix the data and its presentation.

Comment: I agree with @zerkms. You table structure is like saving date as string and formatted like `January 10, 2013.. February 02, 1988..` since it's human readable but difficult during ordering. `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to restructure your table or else you will likely have inefficient query like this,

```
SELECT  Square
FROM    Table1
ORDER   BY         
        CASE WHEN Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}'
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END ASC,
        CASE WHEN Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}'
            THEN LEFT(Square, 2)
            ELSE LEFT(Square, 1)
        END ASC,
        CASE WHEN Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}'
            THEN CAST(RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 2) AS SIGNED)
            ELSE CAST(RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 1) AS SIGNED)
        END ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c749/14)

Or by using `IF`

```
SELECT  Square
FROM    Table1
ORDER   BY Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}' ASC,
           IF(Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}', LEFT(Square, 2), LEFT(Square, 1)),
           CAST(IF(Square REGEXP '^[A-Z]{2}', RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 2), RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 1)) AS SIGNED)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c749/16)

Answer (score 1):

here better way to structure your table

```
 letter  number  
   A      1
   A      2
   A      3
  .....so on
```

then your query will be easy like that

```
  select concat(letter,number) as Square from your_table
  order by letter , number
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d656d/2)

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* this would work, if I am not mistaken:

```
SELECT Square
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN
     SUBSTR(Square, 2, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' 
     THEN CONCAT(LEFT(Square, 2),
         LPAD(RIGHT(Square, LENGTH(Square) - 2), 6, '000000'))
     ELSE CONCAT(LEFT(Square, 1),
         LPAD(RIGHT(Square(LENGTH(Square) - 1), 6, '000000'))
    END
```

Comment: Why do you think appending `zz` to `A2` could put it before `A10`? Don't even point to `SORTED BY`. Definitely not an answer

Comment: @zerkms that was a _useful_ comment, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend changing your db structure if you are able to.  These should be stored in 2 separate fields.  Here is a way you can perform the sort, but also get you going in the right direction to restructure your table:

```
select square, left(square,2) prefix, mid(square,3) suffix
from yourtable
where left(square,2) not regexp '[0-9]'
union
select square, left(square,1) prefix, mid(square,2) suffix
from yourtable
where left(square,2) regexp '[0-9]'
order by prefix, cast(sufix as signed)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7ba4/1)

This way, you can see the prefix and suffix broken out.  This can also be done with case/if statements without the union.

Answer (score -1):

I have no way to fully test this right now but it's working for me and it's an entirely different solution from the preceding one, I would be very interested to see if it works for your problem. Mine was very similar and changing the db structure is not an option as what I am sorting is an user input ... but my solution works whatever the size and is much more simple than what was suggested:

```
SELECT  Square
FROM    Table1
ORDER BY LENGTH(Square), Square
```

Comment: This will push the values with 3 digits eg A10, A20 to the bottom.